# How can I declare a Fragment as hidden in an XML layout

Tags: android, xml, fragment

My activity declares all of its GUI fragments in a single XML layout.  It only needs to display a few of the fragments at launch time; the rest get shown as the user interacts with the app.  A portion of the layout is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_panel"
        android:name="com.example.MapPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/map_panel_height" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_panel"
        android:name="com.example.ListPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map_panel" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detail_panel"
        android:name="com.example.DetailPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map_panel"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

My intention is that the `list_panel` fragment is visible at startup, and the `detail_panel` fragment is hidden until the user selects something from the list.

By default, a fragment starts out with the `isHidden` attribute as false.  That means my activity has to iterate through the loaded fragments and manually call `isHidden(true)` on fragments like `detail_panel` at startup time.

I would prefer to declare the `isHidden` status in the XML layout.  However, setting `android:visibility="gone"` in a `<fragment>` declaration does not change the `isHidden` status, and I can't find any documentation on another attribute that would do the trick.

Is it possible to set an XML attribute on a `<fragment>` to cause it to be hidden?

Note:  I'm not concerned with view visibility, I'm concerned with the `fragment.isHidden()` value.  That affects how FragmentManager manipulates the back stack and performs animations.  If you call `transaction.show(fragment)` on a fragment whose view is invisible or gone, but the `fragment.isHidden()` value is false, then the FragmentManager will not make the view visible.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isHidden() for reference.

Comment: did you try android:visibility="invisible"?

Comment: Yes, I did try "invisible" in addition to "gone".  Neither affect the fragment's isHidden status.

Comment: What do you mean by "inaddition to gone". did you just try "invisible". In this case it will create the fragmment and keep it in invisible state.

Comment: No, setting android:visibility="invisible" inside a <fragment> tag does not affect the isHidden state of the fragment.

Comment: @JayLieske Did you find an answer?

Comment: Hi. Do we have no choice but to hide a fragment in code?

Answer (score 15):

I faced a similar situation, where I had to hide a fragment.

I simply included the fragment inside a LinearLayout and marked the layout to be visible/gone.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 10):

Based off Jyo's post, use this:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.hide(mFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This has worked for me on API Level 23. `mFragment` is the fragment that you want to hide.

Comment: this is the correct answer. you shouldn't hide fragments using view visibility.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a tad late thought it may be helpful for future reference. Visibility is part of the View class - Fragment extends object though not having access to the visibility values. A possibility is making the Fragment a child of a FrameLayout and calling invisible or gone on the layout. This will cause the fragment to appear to be hidden.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Changing the `visibility` state of the View has no effect on the `isHidden` state of the Fragment.

Comment: wrapping the `fragment` around a `FrameLayout` is the simplest and most effective IMHO

Comment: this is against Google recommendations which are to use the FragmentManager to hide/show fragments.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showHideFrgament(final Fragment fragment){

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out);

    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
                    ft.show(fragment);
                    Log.d("hidden","Show");
                } else {
                    ft.hide(fragment);
                    Log.d("Shown","Hide");                        
                }
                ft.commit();

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

we have isVisible Method for fragment 
seeting visibilty to Gone does not take any space
Where as Invisble takes the actual view space.

Comment: You are describing the state of the View, not the `isHidden` state of the fragment.

Comment: this is against Google recommendations which are to use the FragmentManager to hide/show fragments.

Comment: isVisible cannot be changed as it is val in Kotlin